# Empty classList returns true

Tags: javascript, html, boolean

I wonder why the following alert displays while the `classList` is an empty string:

```
<p id="p">Hello, world!</p>
<button id="b">Button</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('b').onclick = function () {
        if (document.getElementById('p').classList) {
            alert('Full!');
        }
    };
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/d3mjv/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `classList` is an object of type `DOMTokenList` with some overridden methods like `toString()` (that's why `alert(document.getElementById('p').classList)` shows an empty string) etc.

So when you execute `if (document.getElementById('p').classList) {` you actually have smth like **if (Object) {** and in that case **if** will pass.

To ensure - see `typeof(document.getElementById('p').classList)` - it will be `collection`. Also try to write in console `document.getElementById('p').classList.__proto__` - you'll see `DOMTokenList`-prototype object that has a link to the `DOMTokenList` contructor (`document.getElementById('p').classList.__proto__.constructor`).

Read more about `DOMTokenList` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList

Answer (score 3):

`classList` exists but has no length. Try with `document.getElementById('p').classList.length` instead.

Comment: If `classList` exists as a regular JavaScript object, then why does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/d3mjv/1/) alert empty? compare with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/d3mjv/2/).